# Flash Animation and Sound Loop

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

ok so im having an issue with Flash CS5.

I have a sound looping, and my animation is only 13 frames long, while the song is like a minute long, so each time the animation loops threw the default "Loop Playback" a new sound audio is played which os overlapping the previous over and over causing a massive echo effect.

Whats the best way to loop both of them insync, or atleast copy and paste the animations frames and make it the length of the song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way would probably be to put your sound and your animation in different movie clips. Every movie clip has its own playhead, and they move independently. So if you put two movieclips on the stage, one containing the sound and another containing the animation, if they have different total numbers of frames they will loop at different times. (Or of course you could put one of the two directly onto the stage, and the other in a movie clip, etc.)

I should add: getting the hang of nesting different contents into different levels of movieclip hierarchy is really the heart an soul of architecting good flash content, this would be a good way to start getting into it. You *could* just leave both the sound and animation on the stage, and copy out the animation a bunch of times (I believe the menu option is Edit > Timeline > Copy Frames), but then if you decide to adjust the animation you'll have to adjust it umpteen times. Or what if you want to change it to 14 frames? And so on.